# Error in initiating RandomForest model in R - Text Analytics

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to set up 3 models - logistic regression, CART and randomForest to model a binary factor "spam" (dependent variable) from a list of independent variables (a Document Term Matrix where rows are the different documents and columns are the terms that appeared).

This is an online course. I did all the typical preprocessing as instructed such as removing punctuation, stop words, stemming, and ensuring the "spam" variable is 
"as.factored" etc.

It worked fine until I got to initiating the randomForest model and I got the error at the end. The course specifically said I did not have to specify other detail like ntree or nodesize - the default would have been used automatically.

After more research, it seems "000" is pointing to a part of my data causing the issue. 000 is actually the first term in my document term matrix. Why does the error said it was not found??

Structure of the data:

Email# "000" "account"... (other terms in emails)..  is spam?

```
1      1     2   ... (any counts)...             0
```

Thank you for shedding some light on this.

```
> emailsSparse$spam = as.factor(emailsSparse$spam)
> set.seed(123)
> spl = sample.split(emailsSparse$spam, 0.7)
Error: could not find function "sample.split"
> library(caTools)
> spl = sample.split(emailsSparse$spam, 0.7)
> train = subset(emailsSparse, spl==TRUE)
> test = subset(emailsSparse, spl==FALSE)
> spamLog = glm(spam ~ ., data=train, family="binomial")
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
spamC
> spamCART = rpart(spam~ ., data=train, method="class")
Error: could not find function "rpart"
> library(rpart)
> library(rpart.plot)
> spamCART = rpart(spam~ ., data=train, method="class")
> set.seed(123)
> spamRF = randomForest(spam ~., data=train)
Error: could not find function "randomForest"
> library(randomForest)
randomForest 4.6-10
Type rfNews() to see new features/changes/bug fixes.
> spamRF = randomForest(spam ~., data=train)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '000' not found
```

Comment: dput() your emailSparse, add what you're expecting to get, and what you're getting and you'll be more likely to get an answer you'll be happy with.

Comment: Need to follow through the online course so I have to stick to using RF I am afraid. but thank you

Comment: add the output of dput(emailSparse) to the question

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/529hx9id2frojt7/dput%28emailsSparse%29.rtf?dl=0

the codes were too long to paste - so i uploaded it. Thank you.

Comment: If you've solved this, please answer it yourself and close it. If not, please add more detail.